# \lessim slanted variation

Tags: symbols

I need a `\leq` symbol underlined like the symbol `\leqslant` (in order to obtain a sort of `\lessim` version of `\leqslant`)

That is, with the `\sim` parallel to the bottom part of `\leq` (and as well integrated as possible).

[image]

Do you know whether such a symbol already exists or is easy to obtain?

Comment: With other words, the `\sim` symbol should be slanted as well or should should have the same slope as the `<`?

Comment: Probably , I did not explain properly. I updated the question with an image. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with my proposition

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using `stackengine` and `graphicx`. Probably you should scale the whole operator down a little bit, but it does what it should be.

If you want this as a macro just do `\newcommand\myop{\ensuremath\mathrel{\raisebox{1pt}{\stackunder{$<$}{\rotatebox{-27}{\resizebox{7pt}{2pt}{$\sim$}}}}}}`.

[image: mathop]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,stackengine,graphicx}
\setstackgap{S}{-1.5pt}

\begin{document}

$a \mathrel{\raisebox{1pt}{\stackunder{$<$}{\rotatebox{-27}{\resizebox{7pt}{2pt}{$\sim$}}}}} b$
$a \leqslant b$
$a \simeq b$

\end{document}
```

*Update:* Use `\boldsymbol{\sim}` with a resizebox of 6.5pt instead (as the OP himself/herself suggested) and the output will look nicer.

Comment: Probably , I did not explain properly. I updated the question with an image. Sorry.

Comment: @CarLaTeX No, rather `\mathrel`, but I will add this in a moment.

Comment: @CarLaTeX You're right, much better now.

Comment: Oh, yes! Egreg will be proud of you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think so (look at the much too thin sim, because of the `\resizebox` and of course the inclusion of `graphicx` just for rotating in **math**).

Comment: He'll find a better solution, then, hahaha!

Comment: I tweaked a bit to adjust to \leqslant positioning, make it a relator, and improve the general looking:
\newcommand{\leqisom}{\mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\stackunder{$<$}{\rotatebox{-27}{\hspace{-1pt}\resizebox{6.5pt}{2pt}{$\boldsymbol{\sim}$}}}}}}

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think that `\leqslant` is horrible; the proposed symbol is even uglier. `;-)`

Comment: OK, @egreg is not proud of you :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oh, no! The proposed solution is good (but I'm not sure it scales in sub/superscripts).

Comment: @egreg we're looking forward to yours!

Comment: @egreg You're correct. Both symbols aren't great, but we can't talk of scaling at the moment.

Comment: @suitangi If the answer solved your problem consider accepting it to mark this question as solved.